# Maven, Android and Eclipse coexistence problems

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, adt, m2e

I am developing Android projects using Maven in Eclipse.

I installed the Android SDK, ADT for Eclipse and the Android Configurator for M2E, which worked fine.

My problem is that when I update the SDK Tools using the Android SDK manager, the ADT plugin update seems to be ready, but the Android Configurator for M2E is not.

Currently the latest Android SDK Tools revision is 20. The Android Configurator is not compatible with it so I have to wait for an update. However, I can't tell when the update is ready because there's no version number for the configurator, and I can only keep trying to install it every day, see if it works and then uninstall it if it doesn't.

Has anyone else had better luck with using Maven with Android in Eclipse?

Comment: That's why I switched to Intellij

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue with the [m2e-android connector](http://rgladwell.github.com/m2e-android) caused by the update for ADT version 20.0.0 that is being worked on:

https://github.com/rgladwell/m2e-android/issues/89

There should be a version number for the m2e-android (currently on 0.4.1) although it may not be obvious simply by browsing the update site. You can stay updated of new releases by following my twitter feed ([@rgladwell](https://twitter.com/rgladwell)) or subscribing to the [maven-android-developers Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/maven-android-developers).

**Update** The new 0.4.2 release fixes the compatibility issues with ADT 20 was released 6th August. Please run an Eclipse update (*Help -> Check for Updates*) and let me know if this resolves your problems.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. My problem is that I can't find out when it will be fixed unless I try to install it and uninstall it every so often to check if it's fixed. Also, this problem will recur every time the Android SDK Tools are updated.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a volunteer project so I can't give you any firm deadlines but a new release will be soon.

Comment: The new 0.4.2 release fixes this issue was released today, please run an Eclipse update (Help -> Check for Updates) and let me know if this resolves your problems.